# Html-List css with chrome and IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, html-lists

I searched around but can not find solution. I do not understand why with chrome and IE disk ul wraps the text and are not aligned. The link is: http://web42.login-33.hoststar.ch/vivasicilia/index.php?option=com_k2&view=item&id=251:alia&Itemid=727

Thanks you for solution!!!

Comment: Can you please highlight your problem with a fiddle? or give more information about it.

Comment: Hi Patrik. I'm sorry but this is the first time I enter this site. If you go to the link I posted, the disks are not aligned horizontally with the text links. With firefox works fine with chrome and IE, the text wraps. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `float: left` from `div.k2ItemsRelatedListVertisagrepal a {}`

and add

```
div.k2ItemsRelatedListVertisagrepal a {
  line-height: 1;
}

div.k2ItemsRelatedListVertisagrepal li h7 {
  line-height: 12px;
}
```

- You dont need to float `<a>` . his parent is already floated

update: 
add

```
div.k2ItemsRelatedListVertisagrepal a {
  line-height: 1 !important;
  display: inline-block !important;
  width: 140px !important;
}
```

its a really ugly fix :(

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry, but eliminating float: left, with FF, IE and chrome
text-overflow: ellipsis; and  white-space:nowrap;  not work's...
Solution's, please?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
.k2ItemsRelatedListVertisagrepal ul {
list-style: none;
}
```

By the way, you have two elements with `id='k2ModuleRelated'`